# Change the categories structure from C# file or fromdashboard to match Algolia's

Tags: c#, .net, algolia

Is there a way to update key-value structure of ALL objects of a given Algolia index in a single go? (or multiple. Just need a way) I am using C#, .NET and i wish to make a call in the controller and update my Algolia Index, so that i can generate heirarchical tree.

eg: i want to change

```
Genre : "cat1 > cat2 >cat3"
```

INTO

```
Genre {
"lvl0" : "cat1" ,
"lvl1" : "cat1>cat2",
"lvl2" : "cat1>cat2>cat3"
}
```

I have thought of few ways but every method seems to ask for objectID and my IDs are not numbered in an ordered way.

1. I am not able to use index.GetObject(), but that needs objectID as well. I want to get ALL object and then use for loop to modify them.
2. I am not able to use PartialUpdateObjects() either, since it needs an ID too.